# No pokemon in remote rural areas?

Tags: pokemon-go

So me and my friends downloaded pokemon go yesterday.  We got drunk, walked 3km and found 0 pokemon, not even one pokemon showed up in the 'pokemon near you' thing.

**Is this normal for remote areas**?(nearest pokestop is ~15km away)

Thanks.

Comment: I'd remove the tidbit about playing in Canada since people like to close the question as 'asking about an unreleased game' -- even though Go is setup in Canada just not available on the App Store for Canadians. With a U.S. Apple ID the game functions as expected.

Comment: This really shouldn't be closed. Absolutely completely not the same as downloading a cracked APK or whatever they do on Android. The question is perfectly fine

Comment: @Ash If you could, since the question has been edited to be on-topic.

Comment: This is, at best, a duplicate.  We have several questions asking about playiing in remote areas.

Comment: @Frank Then it should be closed as a duplicate

Comment: @Insane When the original question was asking about an area it hasn't been released, it's totally fine to close it as it was.  This question isn't going to help others, so there's not much point in keeping it.

Comment: @Frank Right but my point here is had there not been a question about rural areas already, then it's perfectly on topic even more so because it was edited to remove the Canada part. I think the close reason is ridiculous because I'm a U.S. citizen living in Canada and I have the official game from the App Store with my regular old U.S. Apple ID. Should all my questions be closed as 'using in unreleased territory'?

Comment: @Insane, a user editing out "this hasnt been released yet" comments does not automatically remove the unreleased problem. We dont reopen poracy games just because the user removes "I downloaded a cracked version off the internet", afterall. The user is still playing an unreleased game.

Comment: @Timelord64 Except that it's 1. not cracked 2. downloaded legally from the App Store using a U.S. Apple ID. again, should we vote to close my questions because i'm a US citizen living in Canada and simply downloaded the game like anyone else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately the game uses Google Traffic APIs to determine where to place Pokemon. So if you are in the absolute middle of nowhere, what you are seeing is very likely the expected behavior.